# Sharing data between swift classes

Tags: swift

I have this class called `AudioController()` and it has a variable called `sources` which is an array of Strings.

`AudioViewController()` code:

```
import Foundation

class AudioController {
    static let shared = AudioController()
    var sources = [String]()

    init() {
      print("Sources: \(sources)")
      let controller = RemoteCommandController()
      player = QueuedAudioPlayer(remoteCommandController: controller)
      player.remoteCommands = [
        .stop,
        .play,
        .pause,
        .togglePlayPause,
        .next,
        .previous,
        .changePlaybackPosition
      ]
      try? audioSessionController.set(category: .playback)
      try? player.add(items: sources, playWhenReady: false) // fatal error here because sources is nil
    }
}
```

But. On my other `viewcontroller` when trying to pass `sources`:

```
AudioController().sources = ["Shakira"]
```

I get:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and the `print("Sources: \(sources)")` returns `sources []`.

Comment: 1. Replace `AudioController()` with `AudioController.shared`. 2. Show the actual line of code causing the error.

Comment: `sources` can't be `nil` on that line. And the code you posted won't compile. Where is `player` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are strange things here: why you have a shared instance if you're not using it? And then, you're trying to play an empty array, maybe this is the problem. Try to give values **before** starting the player

```
class AudioController {
    static let shared = AudioController()
    var sources: [String]

    init(sources: [String]) {
      self.sources = sources
      print("Sources: \(sources)")
      let controller = RemoteCommandController()
      player = QueuedAudioPlayer(remoteCommandController: controller)
      player.remoteCommands = [
        .stop,
        .play,
        .pause,
        .togglePlayPause,
        .next,
        .previous,
        .changePlaybackPosition
      ]
      try? audioSessionController.set(category: .playback)
      try? player.add(items: self.sources, playWhenReady: false) // fatal error here because sources is nil
    }
}

// then instantiate the controller with sources
AudioController(sources: ["Shakira"])
```

---

However I suggest you to review your design. Maybe it's not a good idea start playing in the `init`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the shared instance (which I think you do), use something like this:

```swift
AudioController.shared.sources = ["Shakira"]
```

You should also probably add `private init() {}` to prevent accidentally initializing the AudioController. This will make a private initializer that cannot be used outside of the AudioController.

The print statement will always print `[]` because when the init function is called, nothing is in the array yet.

Comment: @rmaddy true, however I suspect it's a result of incorrectly using the shared resource (related to the code we can't see)